# How to calculate a total without using a click event (button) in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a simple calculator using C# and I already made it work when I press a button, like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           int a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
           int b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

           if (comboBox1.Text == "+")
               textBox3.Text = (a + b).ToString();

           if (comboBox1.Text == "-") 
               textBox3.Text = (a - b).ToString();

           if (comboBox1.Text == "*")
               textBox3.Text = (a * b).ToString();

           if (comboBox1.Text == "/") 
               textBox3.Text = (a / b).ToString();
       }
```

What I'm trying to do is for the result in textBox3 to change as I choose the operator from the comboBox without having to press a button. I've tried using the Leave event with no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

There is a SelectedIndexChange event you can wire into

Answer (score -1):

```
private void combobox1_textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
       int b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

       if (comboBox1.Text == "+")
           textBox3.Text = (a + b).ToString();

       if (comboBox1.Text == "-") 
           textBox3.Text = (a - b).ToString();

       if (comboBox1.Text == "*")
           textBox3.Text = (a * b).ToString();

       if (comboBox1.Text == "/") 
           textBox3.Text = (a / b).ToString();
}
```

The above is pseduo code, but just add the "textChanged" event and put the code inside like shown above.

Comment: `The comboBox have an event called something along "comboBox1_valueChanged"`  You have time to research this to get it right.